# Create objects in Java using composition

Tags: java

My code is:

```
public class Class1 {

    Class2 class2;

    public Class1(Class2 class2) {
        class2 = new Class2();
    }

    public void print() {
        class2.printMe();
    }
}

public class Class2 {

    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

Print method is throwing null pointer because Class2 object is not created.
Also, I dont want to create an object in constructor -I was thinking to use DI but I am not much aware of it.

Comment: we need a little bit more code... how are you using that classes??

Comment: What is your question exactly, try to be as specific as possible

Comment: I don't see how a NPE is possible here.

Comment: @C-Otto Then re-read the constructor.

Comment: Why are you taking a `Class2` as argument if you don't even use it?

Comment: Your constructor makes no sense. You pass a `Class2` instance into it, then ignore that for no reason and instead overwrite it with a new instance and totally forget to initialize `this.class2`. What was your thinking here?

Comment: I have to use Class2 in class1 using composition and not creating object in Class1's constructor.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the parameter in the constructor of `Class1`. You need to assign it to your `class2`-field instead. There's two ways to fix this:

1. Remove the parameter:

   ```
   public class Class1 {

       Class2 class2;

       public Class1() {
           class2 = new Class2();
       }

       public void print() {
           class2.printMe();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Assign it to the correct field with `this`:

   ```
   public class Class1 {

       Class2 class2;

       public Class1(Class2 class2) {
           this.class2 = class2;
       }

       public void print() {
           class2.printMe();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I did tried this. But how will I get an object of Class 2 ? I never initialized it in my any class.

Comment: @RishabhJain When you instantiate Class1 you would do so:  `Class1 fred = new Class1(new Class2())`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class1{
  Class2 class2;

  public Class1(Class2 class2){
     this.class2=class2;
  }

 }
```

This is how dependency injection using constructor looks like.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working.  2017-08-28 14:29:08,602 ERROR Class1.java:36 - Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Above one is ur complete code? please post complete code if not.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at by Tom, you're not writing a value to the field in the constructor. Instead, you're ignoring the instance given as an argument (which looks like one way to do DI if done correctly!), and overwriting the argument variable with a new instance. This does not influence the field, however.

Try using this constructor instead:

```
public Class1(Class2 class2) {
    this.class2 = class2;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but its throwing null pointer as I have not created the instance of Class2 anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If there is ambiguity about a variable name (in your case it could point to the method parameter as well as the instance field), you need to add "this" to point out which you're referring to. Otherwise it'll point to the method parameter.

```
public Class1(Class2 class2) {
    this.class2 = class2;
}
```

^ This will fix your issue.